# Add Object Level Permissions to Admin Interface of other APP (e.g. auth)

Tags: django, django-admin

I use django-guardian for object level permissions. The documentation how to integrate this into own code is good:
http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/userguide/admin-integration.html

But how can I add this to models of other apps? I don't want to modify the code of e.g. django.contrib.auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in django-reversion's source code. There is a helper called `patch_admin()`. Here is the snippet modified for django-guardian.

```
# Copy of django-reversion helpers.py
def patch_admin(model, admin_site=None):
    """
    Enables version control with full admin integration for a model that has
    already been registered with the django admin site.

    This is excellent for adding version control to existing Django contrib
    applications. 
    """
    admin_site = admin_site or admin.site
    try:
        ModelAdmin = admin_site._registry[model].__class__
    except KeyError:
        raise NotRegistered, "The model %r has not been registered with the admin site." % model
    # Unregister existing admin class.
    admin_site.unregister(model)
    # Register patched admin class.
    class PatchedModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin, VersionAdmin, ModelAdmin): # Remove VersionAdmin, if you don't use reversion.
        pass
    admin_site.register(model, PatchedModelAdmin)

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
patch_admin(Group)
```